# How to list / echo all variables defined in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to find a way to list all the variables defined in an Azure Devops pipeline. I've found examples using `env` in a script but that gets *all* environment variables and any defined in my yaml have their names changed (to upper case and _ instead of .)

What I'd like is just the variables dictionary output.  I've tried

```yaml
- ${{ each value in variables }}:
  - script: echo ${{ value.key }} ${{value.value}}
```

But that makes one CmdLine task for each variable rather than just echoing them all in one task to make it easy to read

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

This answer to a quite similar question might be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69805202/13760443

According to [YK1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529246/yk1) (author of the answer), you can try

```
- script: |
  for var in $(compgen -e); do
     echo $var ${!var};
  done
```

This script will list all variables.

For example, if you use the next code (to set the pipeline's output variable):

```
- script: |
    echo "Checking if terraform plan has changes..."
    if [ -f tfplan ]; then export tfplan_exists=true; else export tfplan_exists=false; fi
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=do_terraform_apply;isOutput=true]$tfplan_exists"
  name: validation_variable
```

The first script will end up printing all env variables including `VALIDATION_VARIABLE_DO_TERRAFORM_APPLY`

Comment: alternatively, just `env`